# Living favicon - how do they do that

Tags: favicon

I came across this http://contrast-ratio.com/ and noticed that the favicon on browser is a living one, means follows whatever color I put in. Here example
[blue on red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOz2U.png)

How do they do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly straight forward to do, especially if you are using jQuery.

All you need to do is query the approrpriate `link` element (this is in the `<head>` of the document), and update it's `href` attribute with the image url or data that you want to display as the icon.

In the case of the website you are looking at, the following script will update the page with a random icon:

```
$('link[rel="shortcut icon"]').attr('href', 'https://picsum.photos/16/16')
```

(note that "https://picsum.photos/16/16" will return a random image with 16x16 dimensions and is used to demonstrate the concept)